# How to loop data at code behind ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Currently, I am looking for a solution to makes my data loop at the code behind?

It is actually an announcement list that query from database which contains the title and contents.

```
cmdDa = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM announcement ORDER BY announcement_PostDT DESC", conn)
ds = New DataSet()

cmdDa.Fill(ds, "announcement")
Dim total_rows_count As Integer = ds.Tables("announcement").Rows.Count - 1

For i = 0 To total_rows_count

   Dim title As String = ds.Tables("announcement").Rows(i).Item("announcement_Title")

   'How do I going to make it display on a label and keeps it loop?
   lbl_announcement_title.Text += title
   'This is not the thing I expect, what I expect is to make it show nicely, like 
   'the next loop will automatically goes to the next line.
Next
```

Should I put it into a panel, list view or anything and loop it? Need help badly!

Comment: Remember that you are working with html so to break the line just add a </br> tag in front of title. Like that lbl_announcement_title.Text += title + "</br>"

Comment: in fact, I still have contents for the announcements! How I going to loop it in orderly :(

Comment: What do you mean when you say "loop it in orderly" ?

Comment: e.g:

Title: Happy Holiday
Content: Today is Saturday

Title: Happy Sunday
Content: Today is Sunday

Comment: Just do the same. Declare an variable for the content:

Dim content As String = ds.Tables("announcement").Rows(i).Item("announcement_Content")

After that you can rename your component lbl_annoucement_title to lbl_annoucement, use it in your lbl_announcement.Text += "Title:"+title+" Content:"+content+"</br>". This way it will work both of the contents will appear.

Comment: To control the order that the rows appear you need to change your sql command.

Comment: How do I going to change it? any guidelines? I appreciate it!

Comment: your actual sql is ordering by PostDT Desc so if you whant to order by title you can change it to ORDER BY announcement_Title ASC or DESC (Ascending or Descending) if you want to order by date and title then just alter to that ORDER BY announcement_PostDT DESC, announcement_Title ASC

Answer (score 0):

To acomplish what you want your code could be like that:

```
cmdDa = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM announcement ORDER BY announcement_PostDT DESC, announcement_Title ASC", conn)
ds = New DataSet()

cmdDa.Fill(ds, "announcement")
Dim total_rows_count As Integer = ds.Tables("announcement").Rows.Count - 1
Dim title As String = String.Empty
Dim content As String = String.Empty
Dim itemText As String = String.Empty
For i = 0 To total_rows_count
   title = ds.Tables("announcement").Rows(i).Item("announcement_Title")
   content = ds.Tables("announcement").Rows(i).Item("announcement_Content")

  itemText = "Title: "+ title + " Content: "+ content
   lbl_announcement_title.Text += itemText + "</br>
Next
```